# Wordpress AJAX Call can't access variables from different function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, global-variables

I am having issues with the scope of javascript. I cannot access these variables I define in a function.

All of the variables inside of the document.onload cannot be accessed by the uploadVideo function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.onload = function() {

      q = JQuery;
      video_form = q("#wb_bc_video_form");
      video_ulid = q("#wb_bc_video_ulid");
      file_input = q("#wb_bc_file_input");
      video_file = file_input.files[0];
      video_size = q("#wp_bc_video_size");
      video_time = q("#wp_bc_video_time");

    };

    function uploadVideo(fileFormField) {
      var formdata = new FormData();
      formdata.append("video", video_file);
      q.ajax(
              {
                type: "POST",
                url: ajaxurl,
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                  start = new Date().getTime();
                  xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                    var loaded = e.loaded / 1048576;
                    var total = e.total / 1048576;
                    video_size.innerHTML = loaded.toPrecision(4) + "(MB / " + total.toPrecision(4) + "MB)&nbsp;";
                    video_time.innerHTML = (new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000 + " Seconds";
                    if (Math.round(loaded) === Math.round(total)) {
                      node(video_form, "p", "Processing video... please wait.");
                    }
                  }, false);
                }
              }
      ).done(function(txt) {
        console.log(txt);
      }).fail(function(xhr, txt) {
        console.log(txt);
      }).always(function(xhr, txt) {
        console.log(txt);
      });

    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Which variables are you trying to access, and for what purpose? Quick answer, define them outside of the function.

Comment: `document.onload` ? does that work. You know Wordpress has jQuery almost built in, and has it's own way of handling ajax request, with premade hooks etc.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I can't access any of the variables in the document.onload function

Comment: Why do you need to access DOM elements before the DOM is loaded? Aside from being illogical, it's not possible.

Comment: You're not even close! You're using `JQuery`, and it's probably called `jQuery`, and you're not using the proper `document.ready` function, and you're using `files[0]` and `innerHTML` on jQuery objects, and you're doing almost everything else wrong as well.

Comment: Just a quick rewrite, but try something closer to this -> http://jsfiddle.net/JbJ6K/1/